# Different Threading.Timer-instances occur on exactly the same time

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I've the following short code sample that shows a strange behaviour of System.Threading.Timer. On startup it shows that both timer-events occur at differnt timestamps. After some keystrokes (3 to 5) both timers are synchronized. They happen exactly at the same time.

How is that possible?

This behaviour can be reproduced using System.Timers.Timer. That's strange and unexpected. We're looking for an explanation for that.

```
new Timer(_ => { Console.WriteLine("1: " + DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("HH:mm:ss,fffffff")); }, null, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(0), TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(400));
Thread.Sleep(10);
new Timer(_ => { Console.WriteLine("2: " + DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("HH:mm:ss,fffffff")); }, null, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(0), TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(400));

while (true)
{
    Console.ReadKey();

    // 100% CPU usage
    for (var i = 0; i < Environment.ProcessorCount; ++i)
    {
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            for (var y = 0; y < 1 << 30; ++y) ;
        }).Start();
    }
}
```

**Please scroll to the right to see the whole line.**

If I change the code so that it uses thread containing a `Thread.Sleep()` all works as expected.

This is the working example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    new Thread(Do).Start();
    Thread.Sleep(10);
    new Thread(Do).Start();

    while (true)
    {
        Console.ReadKey();

        // 100% CPU usage
        for (var i = 0; i < Environment.ProcessorCount; ++i)
        {
            new Thread(() =>
            {
                for (var y = 0; y < 1 << 30; ++y) ;
            }).Start();
        }
    }
}

private static void Do()
{
    var id = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
    while (true)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(400);
        Console.WriteLine(id + ": " + DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("HH:mm:ss,fffffff"));
    }
}
```

**EDIT Some news found**

We had a deeper dive into the system source code of [`System.Thrading.Timer`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/timer.cs,051a39d380760b26). The ctor takes the callback and forwards it to a [`TimerQueueTimer`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/timer.cs,fd01ae537237d3f6,references)-object over an internal method. This object calls this delete in [`CallCallback`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/timer.cs,54bb0997765169d8,references) method. The only call of that method is in [`Fire`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/timer.cs,02e8a3e067bee157,references). A code snippet of that method is:

```
internal void Fire()
{
    bool canceled = false;

    lock (TimerQueue.Instance)
    {
        // prevent ThreadAbort while updating state
        try { }
        finally
        {
            canceled = m_canceled;
            if (!canceled)
                m_callbacksRunning++;
        }
    }

    if (canceled)
        return;

    CallCallback();
```

We found that `lock`-statement on a singleton instance. Currently we think that this lock statement is the reason why the timers are synchronized.

Let's think about that: One of the timers are currently inside of that lock statement. Now we waste a lot of cpu time that causes this thread to stay a little bit longer inside the lock. At the same time the other thread reaches exactly this lock statement. From now on they're synchronized. (With respect to the resolution of `DateTime.UtcNow`.

Is that possible? Might this be the solution of that strange behaviour?

Comment: Pretty important to keep in mind that observed thread synchronization is a pure accident.  But it is likely accident in code like this, it runs off the "heart-beat" of the operating system.  The normal state for the processor cores is for them to be turned off completely, consuming no power.  The clock interrupt wakes them up, ticks 64 times per second by default, it goes looking for how much time has passed and if any threads ought to get the processor.  The same interrupt also updates the clock (DateTime.UtcNow, Environment.TickCount).

Answer (score 0):

Windows isn't a real-time operating system. The resolution for `DateTime.UtcNow` is lower than the time taken for each thread to run so they appear to happen at exactly the same time.

You need to use a higher resolution time keeper to see that they do not happen at exactly the same time. Use `Stopwatch` instead. Write your code like this:

```
var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

new Timer(
    _ => Console.WriteLine("1: " + sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds),
    null,
    TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(0),
    TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(400));

Thread.Sleep(10);
new Timer(
    _ => Console.WriteLine("2: " + sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds),
    null,
    TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(0),
    TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(400));
```

Then you get this output:

```
1: 0.2394
2: 11.1295
2: 452.4451
1: 452.5364
2: 986.9352
1: 986.9899
2: 1553.0689
1: 1553.104
2: 2102.9755
1: 2103.0126
2: 2623.3271
1: 2623.365
2: 3143.6929
1: 3143.7302
2: 3662.3903
1: 3662.4268
2: 4142.4248
1: 4142.465
2: 4629.2655
1: 4629.3208
2: 5160.6276
1: 5160.6878
```

Clearly they aren't executing at the same time.

Comment: Mostly. The problem is not the precision of that timer. `Thread.Sleep` should have nearly the same precision. The problem is that they start differently but after a little waste of cpu performance they synchronize. That's the problem. If both threads start directly one after another I've no problem that the resolution doesn't show any difference. We're starting the timers with a jitter of 10ms that this jitter goes away after cpu time wasting.